# Prevent write to SQL until admin approval

Tags: sql, forms, submit, admin, registration

Gotta question.  On my website I have a registration form that, once submitted, writes the data to a database.  The address that the user provides is used to display their information on a google maps (city, state, country... not SPECIFIC location).  Everything shows up on google maps instantaneously, but I'm worried that something will show up on there that shouldn't.

Say someone submits something on the form... like first_name "Seymour" last_name "Butts".  Obviously, I don't want a marker added that shows Seymour Butts' location.

Is there anyway to submit a form, have it sent to a designated admin for approval, and, once approved, THEN have it write to the sql database?  I think that'd be the best way to do it...  I'm open to suggestions!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Add a field to whatever table you write to that designates whether the item has been approved or not. You can then query the table for blanks to see which items need to be approved, and query for approved items to only show non-Butts items.

Comment: I agree with Stu, add a column to your table called isApproved. When you load your map you can just load the approved ones if you want.

Comment: Pretty straight forward... Seems like this would be the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to an intermediate table, say a "WaitingForApproval" table.

Then you could write an admin tool listing the contents of this table with each item having an "Approve" button next to it, which would trigger the insert into the real table.

Comment: That makes sense... and it doesn't seem like it would be too difficult.  Well, at least not until I try to "approve" from the admin tool... because I would to have the option to "disapprove".

Comment: Know of anything that's demo'd out there that I can lean on why I try to write this?  Doubt I'll find anything that's put together... probably gonna have to go bit by bit.

Comment: Nyaa, just copy the original table and let your Approve button do `INSERT INTO OtherTable SELECT * FROM WaitTable WHERE id=... DELETE FROM WaitTable WHERE id=...`. Pretty straightforward. Stu's answer also makes sense, it depends whether you want unapproved items to be in your real table or not. When there are lots of bad items being added and admins are lazy, it could clog your table. Otherwise there is no real difference, you can choose either way to go.